# Manual setup of protractor not working on 1.3.1 anymore

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Due to multiple interactive browser setup during tests, I have to setup protractor manually. My setup is from protractor 0.19. After I upgraded to 1.3.1 'protractor/jasminewd' is missing.

Has the manual setup process changed? Can anyone point me in the right direction? The head of my setup script:

```
var protractor = require('protractor');
require('protractor/jasminewd');
var utils = require('./utils.js');

//needed for jenkins
require('jasmine-reporters');
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
    new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter('xmloutput', true, true));

var conf =  utils.readConfig();
var host = conf['server:main'].host;
var port = conf['server:main'].port;
var testbrowser = utils.readConfig()['integrationtest'].browser;


//setup
var driver1 = new protractor.Builder().
    usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub').
    withCapabilities({'browserName': testbrowser}).build();


driver1.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(15000);
var browser = protractor.wrapDriver(driver1);
protractor.setInstance(browser);
var by = protractor.By;
var element = browser.element;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jasminewd has been moved to its own npm module now: https://www.npmjs.org/package/jasminewd. 
If you include jasminewd in your package.json and use

```
 require('jasminewd');
```

instead of

```
  require('protractor/jasminewd')
```

everything should just work

Comment: Unfortunately then I get `[TypeError: Cannot read property 'matcherFn_' of undefined]`

Comment: Solved it, installed jasmine-node in the wrong directory. With your changes it is running again. Thank you.